# Python 3.x Connect to account with request POST

Tags: python, session

I am trying to connect to the account at adidas.fr and for that I have written such script:

```
session = requests.Session()

user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36"

session.headers["User-Agent"]=user_agent

result=session.get('https://cp.adidas.fr/web/eCom/fr_FR/loadsignin')

tree = html.fromstring(result.text)

authenticity_token = tree.xpath("//input[@name='CSRFToken']/@value")

print(authenticity_token[0])

login_data = {
    'username': 'mail@gmail.com',
    'password': 'pass',
    'CSRFToken' :str(authenticity_token[0]),
             }

R=session.post('https://cp.adidas.fr/web/eCom/fr_FR/loadsignin',data=login_data)

print(R.text)
```

Then i try to go on a page who is needed to be connected but i can't access . So i think my post request is not good, but i can't find what i make wrong. Can someone help ? Thanks

Comment: why do you use `get()` if you need `post()` ?

Comment: Sorry its post just a mistake when i writte it

Comment: what result do you get ? what text do you see? Maybe there is some usefull information. Are you sure it uses field names `username`, 'passwor` ? Are you sure it doesn't send other fields - even empty ? Server can check this fields too. You can use `DevTools` (tab `Network`) in Chrome/Firefox to check what data sends browser.

Comment: yes i use TAMPER data to make my payload